# Issues while using ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')

Tags: php, ini-set

I would like to know, is there any issues(bad to server) while using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` on number of occasions?

The reason why I need to know this is, I'm now working in a project where use of join queries is high. We are only fetch required data's to avoid maximum load but in some situation where data exceeds 20000+ record, execution dies & shows `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

I know Error 500 may be cause of lot other issues, so I have checked it & found the reason was because of PHP execution memory limit exceeding(256M). When I set `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` on my code, query executed correctly.

The above explanation is just a situation/scenario, no need to consider that & Yes, I agree that using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` is a bad practice. So, my question is clearly to know ***is there any issue on using ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') multiple times*** on different sections of a project (like sever issues or so). If yes, what are they?

Comment: The reason for such limit is to protect your system from scripts out of control. So raising that limit is a thread to your system. Question is why your scripts need such a huge amount of memory, _that_ is what you should fix instead of raising that limit. Typically the issue is that query results are copied in memory, sometimes multiple times, instead of processing them in a serial manner. This results in the script using a memory footprint raising in size depending on the query result instead of a constant memory usage. A sign of a questionable implementation.

Comment: Setting the memory limit to "unlimited" is indeed a _very_ bad idea. A few requests and your server will go down. Why would you ever need to fetch 20000+ records in one go? I would rather rethink the architecture.

Comment: Im a developer I know its bad to take lot data, client requirements need to be satisfied. So @arkascha, I do not requires unlimited memory, I will check how much memory is required & set it as you suggested. Good suggestion that.

Comment: "Why would you ever need to fetch 20000+ records in one go?" Looks like @Sinto needs to look up a concept called Pagination...

Comment: As long as you're in testing process, you can go for an infinite limit(take care of your computer, tho).Otherwise, it's a bad idea to allocate whole memory to PHP.

Comment: @justderb, :-) pagination's are all here man. requires some count & count related different calculations.

Comment: No, that is _not_ what I suggested. I did _not_ at all say: leave everything as it is, just find out what memory size you _really_ need. I said: fix your code to process the data in a clean serial manner without doubling the data again and again in memory.

Comment: You can still do count operations by paging your queries... Just take each page and distill it into the data you need and throw out the rest to keep memory low.

Comment: @arkascha, yes, i will do that. I not going to leaving the code with unlimited memory, will check & set a limit.

Comment: Is that a joke? That last comment reads as if you refuse to read or understand what I wrote by purpose.

Comment: @justderb, good.

Comment: I suggest you post the relevant parts of your code where the query result is processed.

Comment: @arkascha, No jokes on work. some time I understood wrong, sorry man.

Comment: _"client requirements need to be satisfied"_ - Sure, but it's your job to do it well and fetching 20000+ records in one go isn't it. You can fetch data in batches instead of it all in one go. You haven't even told us _why_ you need all those records. Print to screen? XML? Excel? Json? API?

Comment: @arkascha & magnus, got that.

Answer (score 1):

`ini_set` will set the configuration option during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

so `ini_set` will only works on the current php process. The next time a request coming, a new php process will read `php.ini` first to get the `memory_limit` and then you can use `ini_set` to set the value to -1.

you can use `ini_get` to check `memory_limit` to avoid set memory_limit multiple times, and check the return value of `ini_set` to ensure success.

using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` is a bad idea. Try to use pagination to avoid fetch all data at a time.